# TYPED_TEST for a class template <typename T, size_t size>

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, c++14, googletest

I am trying to write a unit tests for a templated class named Client. Couldn't succeed in compiling the unitTests code. Not sure how to pass both the `class / typename T` and the `size_t size` parameters in unit Testing. I have made a git repo `git clone https://github.com/BhanuKiranChaluvadi/gtest-minimal-example.git` in case if you wish to compile on local machine and look into the issue.

```
#pragma once

#include <array>

namespace inputs
{
    template <typename T, size_t size>
    class IClient
    {
    public:
        using ClientType = std::array<T, size>;
        virtual const ClientType &getID() const = 0;
        virtual bool isID(const ClientType &anotherID) const = 0;
    };

    template <typename T, size_t size>
    class Client : public IClient<T, size>
    {
    public:
        using ClientT = std::array<T, size>;

        Client(const ClientT &ID) : ID(ID) {}
        Client(const ClientT &&ID) : ID(std::move(ID)) {}

        inline const ClientT &getID() const override { return ID; }
        inline bool isID(const ClientT &anotherID) const override { return ID == anotherID; }

        inline bool operator==(const Client &anotherClient) { return ID == anotherClient.getID(); }

    private:
        ClientT ID;
    };

} // namespace inputs
```

And this is how my google tests looks like

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <type_traits>
#include "client.hpp"
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

using namespace inputs;

namespace inputs_test
{

    template <class T, size_t size>
    class ClientTest : public testing::Test
    {
    };

    using testing::Types;

    // The list of types we want to test.
    typedef Types<std::pair<int8_t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 16>>,
                                std::pair<uint8_t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 24>>>
            Implementations;

    TYPED_TEST_CASE(ClientTest, Implementations);

    TYPED_TEST(ClientTest, shouldReturnSetID)
    {
        typename TypeParam::first_type data_type;
        typename TypeParam::second_type size;
        // static constexpr std::size_t n = TypeParam::value;
        EXPECT_TRUE(true);
    }

} // namespace inputs_test
```

The templated Client class expected either `<int8_t, 16>` or `<uint8_t, 24>`. I am not sure how to pass `size_t` templated argument.

```
test/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h:174:38: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
  174 |     typedef CaseName<gtest_TypeParam_> TestFixture; \
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the `TYPED_TEST` macro resolves to? Also, can you provide a [mcve]? Add to that the output it produces, so people can match the error message to the code causing it. BTW: I think the important distinction is that you're using non-type template parameters (the MCVE will verify that). Consider adding that to your search and to your question title if I guessed right.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  This is the exact code i am using, just copy pasted it here. I am using `Ubuntu 20.04`  and `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`  and i compiled the google test from the latest master

Comment: I don't question that it's copied from your actual code. However, it's still incomplete, is still split into two files and contains code that obviously isn't necessary. Make sure I can copy'n'paste it into a file and see the exact same issue.

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt  I have added a github repo in the description of the question. You can clone and perform cmake .and make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to write a `ClientTest` class which takes the `std::tuple` (or `std::pair`) as a single template argument and splits it up into the two template parameters `T` and `size` again using [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element). Then it instantiates `Client<T, size>` as a class member. This can then be used to perform the wished tests:

```
namespace inputs_test {
  template <typename Tup>
  class ClientTest: public testing::Test {
    using T = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, Tup>;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, Tup>::value;
    using ClientT = typename inputs::Client<T, size>::ClientT;

    protected:
      ClientTest() noexcept 
        : id{new ClientT{}}, client{new inputs::Client<T, size>{*id}} {
        return;
      }

      ~ClientTest() noexcept {
        delete id;
        delete client;
      }

      ClientT* id;
      inputs::Client<T, size>* client;
  };

  typedef testing::Types<std::tuple<std::int8_t,  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 16>>,
                         std::tuple<std::uint8_t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 24>>>
          Implementations;

  TYPED_TEST_CASE(ClientTest, Implementations);

  TYPED_TEST(ClientTest, shouldReturnSetID) {
    EXPECT_EQ(this->client->getID(), *this->id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @2b-t ,  I tried compiling above code but unfortunately there is compilation error because of some deprecated functions `gmock-matchers.h:432:67: error: implicitly-declared ‘testing::internal::EndsWithMatcher<std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t> >::EndsWithMatcher(const testing::internal::EndsWithMatcher<std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t> >&)’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-copy]`. If you wish compile by yourself please refer to github page in the question.

Comment: @BhanuKiran It compiles on Ubuntu 18.04 with `sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev` and GCC 7.5.0. What does it say? I have not paid attention to the C++ standard. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: @BhanuKiran I have several alternatives of g++ installed. I will try to switch and clone your repo. Let's see...

Comment: Hi @2b-t , I tried on debian10 with gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0 the compilation was successfull But on Ubuntu 20.04 and  gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 was failing

Comment: @BhanuKiran I have just played around with several versions. It compiles fine with your Github project and g++7.5.0 and 9.2.1 as wll as clang 12.0.1. In other g++ versions adding the compilation flag `-Wno-error=deprecated-copy` to ignore the deprecation warning works. Actually it depends on what the library is compiled with. If I compile the library with `7.5.0` and then use `10.3.0` or  `11.1.0` it works regardless. I think it is a problem of the `googletest` library and not of my code itself.